# Powershell copy file to folder if filename contains foldername

Tags: powershell

I tried to run the following code so sort some bank documents to respective folders. If the filename contains a folder name from the same directory, the file should be moved to the matching folder. If none of the foldernames are part of a file name, the respective file should be moved to the folder `Other`.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

$FileType = "*.pdf"
$folder = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\Myname\Documents" -Filter $FileType

$map = @{
    Wertpapierabrechnung = "*$Wertpapierabrechnung*"
    Wertpapierertrag = "*_Wertpapierertrag*"
    Kontoauszug = "*$Kontoauszug*"
    Depotauszug = "*$Depotauszug*"
    Kapitalmaßnahmen = "*$Kapitalmaßnahmen*"
}

ForEach($file in $folder)
{
    $file
    $key = $file.BaseName
    $key
    $map.Keys
    if ($key -like $map.Keys){

        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination ### SOME PATH JOINING ###

        }
    else{

    "Copy Item did not work."}
}
```

However I am always running through the else loop. I couldn't figure out why. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "-like" only works with one string on the right side and no arrays so you might need to break this down to iterate though the values in $map.keys and check the values one by one

Comment: Title says copy, text means move - code will again copy? I'd use a regular expression with an alternation (OR) and if it matches move accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear how the parts you look for look like and how the folders are named.

Sample tree before:

```
> tree /F
│   bar Wertpapierertrag 2016-04-08.pdf
│   baz Kontoauszug 2018-01-30.pdf
│   blah Depotauszug 2017-10-15.pdf
│   foo other 2019-05-19.pdf
│   foo Wertpapierabrechnung 2017-10-15.pdf
│   test Kapitalmaßnahmen 2016-04-08.pdf
│
├───Depotauszug
├───Kapitalmaßnahmen
├───Kontoauszug
├───Other
├───Wertpapierabrechnung
└───Wertpapierertrag
```

Running this script

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\19\SO_56211858.ps1
$Folder = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments") 
$FileType = "*.pdf"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter $FileType

$RE = [regex]"(Kapitalmaßnahmen|Kontoauszug|Wertpapierabrechnung|Wertpapierertrag|Depotauszug)"
# alternativly build the RegEx from current subfolder names (might need escaping)
# $RE = [regex]((Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Directory -Name) -Join '|')

ForEach($file in $Files){
    if ($file.BaseName -Match $RE){
        $file | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path $Folder $Matches[0]) -WhatIf
    } else {
        $file | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path $Folder "Other") -WhatIf
    }
}
```

If the output look OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf` parameters.

Tree after script ran:

```
> tree /F

├───Depotauszug
│       blah Depotauszug 2017-10-15.pdf
│
├───Kapitalmaßnahmen
│       test Kapitalmaßnahmen 2016-04-08.pdf
│
├───Kontoauszug
│       baz Kontoauszug 2018-01-30.pdf
│
├───Other
│       foo other 2019-05-19.pdf
│
├───Wertpapierabrechnung
│       foo Wertpapierabrechnung 2017-10-15.pdf
│
└───Wertpapierertrag
        bar Wertpapierertrag 2016-04-08.pdf
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Is it possible to add a user dialog, in style of "Save as..." or "Open", like in standard software, to define the folder location?

Comment: See this question & answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412617/get-a-folder-path-from-the-explorer-menu-to-a-powershell-variable

Comment: Both work perfectly. Is there a way to formulate this even more generic? Somewhat like: If folder name is included in file name move it to this folder. So without explicitly stating the folder names as we do right now? That would be so awesome!

Comment: See my edit with the commented out way to build the regex. That should work with simple subfolder names, problem are eventually contained regex chars like `\*+?|{[()^$.#` which need to be escaped (could be done automatically with `[regex]::Escape()` but requires a more complex command.)

Comment: It works without ```[regex]::Escpae()``` for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you notice that I did the edit, even before you asked for it? ;-)